# How to combine two functions but change two separate states individually

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two items which have separate states and a function which toggles their state. How can I change the state of each item using only one function?

The items:

```
<Form.Check
    type="switch"
    id="smsNotificationSwitch"
    label="SMS Notifications"
    checked={this.state.smsNotifications}
    onChange={this.toggleSMSSwitch}
/>
<Form.Check
    type="switch"
    label="Email Notifications"
    id="emailNotificationSwitch"
    checked={this.state.emailNotifications}
    onChange={this.toggleEmailSwitch}
/>
```

The state:

```
state = {
    smsNotifications: true,
    emailNotifications: true,
}
```

the functions I would like to combine:

```
toggleSMSSwitch = () => {
  this.setState((prevState) => (
      {smsNotifications: !this.state.smsNotifications}));
};
toggleEmailSwitch = () => {
  this.setState((prevState) => (
      {emailNotifications: !this.state.emailNotifications})
  );
};
```

I am asking to learn more than anything else.

Comment: I should probably brush up on my JS first as I didn't think much into that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `name` attribute as the same as the state variable name. On `onChange` handler you can get `name` from the event param.

```html
<Form.Check
    name="smsNotifications"
    type="switch"
    id="smsNotificationSwitch"
    label="SMS Notifications"
    checked={this.state.smsNotifications}
    onChange={this.toggleSwitch}
/>
<Form.Check
    name="emailNotifications"
    type="switch"
    label="Email Notifications"
    id="emailNotificationSwitch"
    checked={this.state.emailNotifications}
    onChange={this.toggleSwitch}
/>
```

```js
toggleSwitch = event => {
  const { name } = event.target;
  this.setState({ [name]: !this.state[name] });
};
```

Comment: I removed the `name` attribute and changed the `id` attribute to be the same name as the state. Seems this works as well. So I assume `{ name }` is pulling the name from... the `event.target`, correct? We could put `{ label }` if we wanted? It has been awhile since I have done javascript but I am starting to recall.

Comment: Yes. Correct. You can get `id` from `event.target`.

Comment: Or essentially *any* attribute... Got it! Thanks!